# What is the difference between $\operatorname{proj}_L(x)$ and $\|\operatorname{proj}_L(x)\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let the straight line $L$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ pass through the origin $0$, parallel to a non-zero vector $v$. Let $u$ be another vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$.
>
> Calculate $\operatorname{proj}_L(x)$ and $\|\operatorname{proj}_L(x)\|$ when $n = 3$, $v = (3,1,-7)$ and $u = (1,0,5)$.

First is, I don't get the difference between $\operatorname{proj}_L(x)$ and $\|\operatorname{proj}_L(x)\|$.

I am assuming that the $\|\operatorname{proj}_L(x)\|$ is asking for the component of vector of $u$ that is parallel to vector $v$. And what is $\operatorname{proj}_L(x)$?

Second, I haven't encountered $n$ in the examples given on my textbook and I'm confused.

Comment: I've tried to format your question. I had to make some educated guesses about what you meant, so please look over the question to see if anything needs changing. You've also asked a few questions now; you should start looking into how to format these questions yourself. We have a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for doing so. You can also see how I've formatted your question by pressing the edit button.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it was written like $\mathbb{R}^n$, it means the space of $n$-dimensional real vectors, for some natural number $n$. In this question, though, the vectors are all 3-dimensional, so it would make more sense to refer to just $\mathbb{R}^3$.

It would also be good to check with your instructor about the notation which may be specific to your class, but in general if $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector, then $||\mathbf{v}||$ is the norm, or length, of the vector, so $\textrm{proj}_L (x)$ will be the vector representing the projection of $x$ onto the line $L$, and $||\textrm{proj}_L (x)||$ will be its length.